# Insert the contents of a notepad at specific location in a word document

Tags: ms-word, notepad

We work mostly on COBOL, and we run quite a huge number of jobs everyday. As per our process requirement we need to capture the SDSF outputs in a document. Each job has around 4/5 outputs that we need to copy in a document. We have written a rexx program which spins all the jobs.

The documentation is time consuming. We could FTP the all the outputs to a notepad, but I need a way to insert the contents of the notepad into specific locations in a word documents. Process standards require us to maintain all the outputs in a word document.

The word doc would be having details about the job, and after that the output needs to be copied.

Can this be done?

Comment: Your process standards are insane.

Comment: you bet! But this is a new process, we are still setting up and juggling things.